# how to compare two list of lists and then write data to excel in python

Tags: python, excel, list, csv, export-to-csv

I have two `list of lists` in `python` which looks like this:

**list1:**

```
[['10001', 'Jason', 'University of Utah School of Medicine'],
 ['10007', 'Zhang', 'Duke'],
 ['10016', 'Som', 'Dana-Farber']]
```

**list2:**

```
[['Som', 'mrcc', 'Wed Dec 20 18:36:28 +0000 2017', '10016'],
 ['David', 'mrcc', 'Wed Dec 20 18:36:38 +0000 2017', '10013'],
 ['Kristen', 'mrcc gro', 'Wed Dec 20 18:37:24 +0000 2017', '10045'],
 ['Zhang', 'wan mrcc', 'Wed Dec 20 18:38:44 +0000 2017', '10007']]
```

Now I want to write data to an `excel file` based on comparing data between these two `list of lists`. The structure of my excel file is as below:[image]

For comparisons what I want to do is to see if the last value of each list in `list2` is present in list in `list1`. So for above sample lists `10016` in 1st list in `list2` is present in `list1`. So if its present then I want to write following values in excel row:

[`Yes`,`value2 from 3rd list of list1`, `value 3 in 3rd list oflist1`, `value 2 in 1st list oflist2`, `value3 in 1st list of list2`, `value 1 in 3rd list of list1`]

If the last value of each list in `list2` is not present in `list1` then write following to excel file:

[`No`,`N/A`,`N/A`,`value 2 in current list of list2`, `value3 in current list of list2`, `value 4 in current list of list2`]

I am aware of packages like `xlwt` in `python` that are used for writing to `excel files` but I am unable to get how do I write while doing such a comparison as above?

**UPDATE**: Here is what I have so far now:

```
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")


sheet1.write(0, 0, "User ID Present?")
sheet1.write(0, 1, "User Name")
sheet1.write(0, 2, "Center Name")
sheet1.write(0, 3, "Text")
sheet1.write(0, 4, "Date")
sheet1.write(0, 5, "User ID")

i=1
for items2 in list2:

    for items1 in list1:

        if items2[3] in items1[0]:
            sheet1.write(i, 0, "Yes")
            sheet1.write(i, 1, items1[1])
            sheet1.write(i, 2, items1[2])
            sheet1.write(i, 3, items2[1])
            sheet1.write(i, 4, items2[2])
            sheet1.write(i, 5, items1[0])
        else:
            sheet1.write(i, 0, "No")
            sheet1.write(i, 1, 'N/A')
            sheet1.write(i, 2, 'N/A')
            sheet1.write(i, 3, items2[1])
            sheet1.write(i, 4, items2[2])
            sheet1.write(i, 5, items2[3])
    i=i+1
book.save("Sample_Report_V1.xlsx")
```

When I run this code it executes without error but when I try to open the file I get error as the `file cannot be opened due to wrong file format or file extension`

list1 and list2 are two list of lists as I have described above.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, can you show us and describe how it failed?

Comment: @glibdud I tried `if a == b for a, b in zip(listA, listB) for listA, listB in zip(list2, list1):` but I know this is not the correct syntax. I have added it to my post above as well

Comment: @glibdud I have made more modifications to my code above after some try

Comment: That's looking a lot better. Now all you're missing is a description of what your code is doing that's wrong.

Comment: @glibdud When I run this code it executes without error but when I try to open the file I get error as the `file cannot be opened due to wrong file format or file extension`

Comment: Do you get the same if you save it as `.xls` instead of `.xlsx`?

Comment: @glibdud When I do `.xls` then it doesn't show up as an excel file

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "show up", but if you absolutely have to use the newer `.xlsx` format you'll need to use a different module, like xlsxwriter or openpyxl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is straight forward, it is just the syntax and how you organize the code. Here is my approach to your problem:

```
import csv

def merge(list1, list2):
    lookup = {row[0]: row for row in list1}
    for row2 in list2:
        value = row2[-1]
        if value in lookup:
            row1 = lookup[value]
            yield 'Yes', row1[1], row1[2], row2[1], row2[2], row1[0]
        else:
            yield 'No', 'N/A', 'N/A', row2[1], row2[2], row2[3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = [
        ['10001', 'Jason', 'University of Utah School of Medicine'],
        ['10007', 'Zhang', 'Duke'],
        ['10016', 'Som', 'Dana-Farber']]
    list2 = [
        ['Som', 'mrcc', 'Wed Dec 20 18:36:28 +0000 2017', '10016'],
        ['David', 'mrcc', 'Wed Dec 20 18:36:38 +0000 2017', '10013'],
        ['Kristen', 'mrcc gro', 'Wed Dec 20 18:37:24 +0000 2017', '10045'],
        ['Zhang', 'wan mrcc', 'Wed Dec 20 18:38:44 +0000 2017', '10007']]

    rows = merge(list1, list2)
    with open('merge_lists.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(['User ID Present?', 'User Name', 'Center Name',
            'Text', 'Date', 'User ID'])
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

## Notes

- The procedure you describe is in function `merge`.
- To make looking up easier, I created a dictionary called `lookup` where the user IDs are the keys, and the rows are the values.
- By *writing to excel file*, I guess you meant the CSV file format

## Update

My original answer outputs to a CSV file, which I think the easiest to deal with. You can open that file in Excel without any difficulty. However, I have a feeling that you are insisting on writing to Excel format, so I spent some time to learn `xlwt` enough to use it. Here is my updated solution. Please note that this module deals with an older .xls file format, not the newer .xlsx format. If you save to .xlsx, Excel will not be able to open it.

```
import xlwt

def merge(list1, list2):
    lookup = {row[0]: row for row in list1}
    for row2 in list2:
        value = row2[-1]
        if value in lookup:
            row1 = lookup[value]
            yield 'Yes', row1[1], row1[2], row2[1], row2[2], row1[0]
        else:
            yield 'No', 'N/A', 'N/A', row2[1], row2[2], row2[3]

def write_row(sheet, row, row_number, starting_column_number=0):
    for column_number, cell in enumerate(row, starting_column_number):
        sheet.write(row_number, column_number, cell)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = [
        ['10001', 'Jason', 'University of Utah School of Medicine'],
        ['10007', 'Zhang', 'Duke'],
        ['10016', 'Som', 'Dana-Farber']]
    list2 = [
        ['Som', 'mrcc', 'Wed Dec 20 18:36:28 +0000 2017', '10016'],
        ['David', 'mrcc', 'Wed Dec 20 18:36:38 +0000 2017', '10013'],
        ['Kristen', 'mrcc gro', 'Wed Dec 20 18:37:24 +0000 2017', '10045'],
        ['Zhang', 'wan mrcc', 'Wed Dec 20 18:38:44 +0000 2017', '10007']]

    rows = merge(list1, list2)
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

    write_row(
        worksheet,
        'User ID Present?,User Name,Center Name,Text,Date,User ID'.split(','),
        row_number=0)

    for row_number, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        write_row(worksheet, row, row_number)

    workbook.save('Sample_Report_V1.xls')
```

Comment: by writing to excel file I meant writing to `xlsx` file format

Comment: when I try to open csv file in excel I see an empty row after each row. So there is one row of data and then an empty row and then another row of data

Comment: To deal with empty rows, replace `'w'` with `'wb'` in the `open` function call.

Comment: Please see my update in which I output to Excel .xls format